# Joining Two Different Dataframes on Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two dataframes:

```
df1:                          df2:
+-------------------+----+    +-------------------+-----+
|  Timestamp        |data|    |  Timestamp        |stuff|
+-------------------+----+    +-------------------+-----+
|2019/04/02 11:00:01| 111|    |2019/04/02 11:00:14|  101|
|2019/04/02 11:00:15| 222|    |2019/04/02 11:00:15|  202|
|2019/04/02 11:00:29| 333|    |2019/04/02 11:00:16|  303|
|2019/04/02 11:00:30| 444|    |2019/04/02 11:00:30|  404|
+-------------------+----+    |2019/04/02 11:00:31|  505|
                              +-------------------+-----+
```

Without looping through every row of df2, I am trying to join the two dataframes based on the timestamp. So for every row in df2, it will "add" data from df1 that was at that particular time. In this example, the resulting dataframe would be:

```
Adding df1 data to df2:
+-------------------+-----+----+
|  Timestamp        |stuff|data|
+-------------------+-----+----+
|2019/04/02 11:00:14|  101| 111|
|2019/04/02 11:00:15|  202| 222|
|2019/04/02 11:00:16|  303| 222|
|2019/04/02 11:00:30|  404| 444|
|2019/04/02 11:00:31|  505|None|
+-------------------+-----+----+
```

Looping through each row of df2 then comparing to each df1 is very inefficient. Is there another way?

Comment: The output does not look *based on Timestamp* to me, rather based on index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])

df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='Timestamp')
print (df)
            Timestamp  stuff  data
0 2019-04-02 11:00:14    101   111
1 2019-04-02 11:00:15    202   222
2 2019-04-02 11:00:16    303   222
3 2019-04-02 11:00:30    404   444
```

Also is possible change order `df1` with `df2` and add parameter `direction='forward'`:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Timestamp', direction='forward')
print (df)
            Timestamp  data  stuff
0 2019-04-02 11:00:01   111  101.0
1 2019-04-02 11:00:15   222  202.0
2 2019-04-02 11:00:29   333  404.0
3 2019-04-02 11:00:30   444  404.0
4 2019-04-02 11:00:31   505    NaN
```

---

```
#default direction='backward'
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Timestamp')
print (df)
            Timestamp  data  stuff
0 2019-04-02 11:00:01   111    NaN
1 2019-04-02 11:00:15   222  202.0
2 2019-04-02 11:00:29   333  303.0
3 2019-04-02 11:00:30   444  404.0
4 2019-04-02 11:00:31   505  404.0
```

Comment: direction='forward' or even direction field itself can't change the order of df1 or df2. it doesn't make the left goes to right or right goes to left. what it does is the order of search the result upwards or downwards

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Timestamp'], right_on=['Timestamp'])
```

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation to why this is a solution. Thanks