# Filter a data frame with similar o near time values (vlookup in dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, vlookup

I'd like to merge two data frames with near times values leaving one index fixed to search in the other data frame (similar to vlookup in excel). Can you recommend another worflow?

I followed this process but is not working

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv data
path = r"C:\Users\Documents\"
df1 = pd.read_csv(path + '\obs_heads.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(path + '\sim.csv')

t = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="A2")
print(t)
```

Input:

**Data frame 1:**

[image: input1]

**Data frame 2:**

[image: input2]

**Output:**

[image: output]

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI2i1.png)
Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site frowns upon questions like "please write this code for me" or "tell me how to do this".  You need to make an attempt at a solution and then show us what code you have and ask questions when you get stuck.  Explaining to you how to use a 2D data manipulation library like Pandas is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  I'm sure there are dozens, if not hundreds of tutorials on how to use Pandas to solve problems like these.  I would suggest that you Google for a few of those.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing more posts here and I found the answer: Thanks to all the community

[Joining Two Different Dataframes on Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746731/joining-two-different-dataframes-on-timestamp)

[Pandas date range returns "could not convert string to Timestamp" for yyyy-ww](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326386/pandas-date-range-returns-could-not-convert-string-to-timestamp-for-yyyy-ww)

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv data
path = r"C:\Users\1"
df1 = pd.read_csv(path + '\obs_heads2.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(path + '\HEAD_compiled_export.csv')

df1['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Times'])
df1=df1.set_index('Times')
df2['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Times'])
df2=df2.set_index('Times')

tol = pd.Timedelta('5 minute')
t=pd.merge_asof(left=df1,right=df2,right_index=True,left_index=True,direction='nearest',tolerance=tol)
t.to_csv( path +"\File Name.csv")
```